# Node Js ssh: connect to host port 22. No route to host

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, ssh

Hi I in an attempt to connect to more than one aws account I did a number of stuff that has led to this error. "ssh: connect to host abc.com port 22: No route to host" I dont know what the problem is or how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of issue occurs mostly due to following reasons:

- Maybe your device is not properly connected to internet. Check your internet connection and try to load again.
- May be config file has incorrect information. Check your config file has correct information. Check your ssh directory and ensure that ssh key exists.

Comment: thank you it was due to internet connection. now it's working.

Comment: yeah sure. This may be also occor due to incorrect information in config file

Comment: or due to ssh key file missing